# Pressing for example on listWidget that it appeared in TextEdit?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm doing my raster calculator in Qgis, I'm stuck in the moment how to link my listWidget with textEdit

An example like this is done in a raster calculator qgis
[image]

I want also listWidget Raster Chanel associate with expression textedit
[image]

A question as at pressing for example on 2012 that it appeared in Text edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you would do:

- Listen to a [double click signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#itemDoubleClicked) from the listwidget with a connect

  ```
  self.dlg.listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.my_function)
  ```
- Get the text from your current selection
- Update/insert the retrieved text into your qtextedit [with this function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#insertPlainText)

  ```
  def my_function(self, txt):
      print txt.text() # for testing
      self.dlg.textEdit.insertPlainText(txt.text())
  ```

A side note: Keep references to your files so you can make your calculations. and have a look at the [QT manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/) for further references.

Comment: I inserted self.dlg.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.click) Then the current text with variable: name = self.dlg.listWidget.currentItem().text() Now when it comes to textCursor().insertText(); I can not understand
, tell my please

Comment: After all, I need to click on the List widget to insert it into TextEdit, and not vice versa

Comment: @vazagena see my edit hope it is clearer now :)